# Need Jar Files for Appengine Samples

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jar, google-cloud-datastore

I need to run code samples that are on this page:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries

I've been able to locate jars for all but the following:

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.Filter;
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.CompositeFilter;
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.CompositeFilterOperator;
```

- Can anyone point me to where they are located?
- I'm also a bit concerned that because I'm getting jar files individually
  that I might run into some compatibility issues. Is there one
  location that has jars for all the samples on the page I mentioned above?

Thx,
Steve

Comment: Maybe you can download the source and build the jars yourself

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [GAE SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads) and include it on you project. All those classes are included in there.

GAE is a pretty complex PAAS product. You'll need to setup the whole platform in order to use it, you cant just use some bits of it on its own.